# JIRA OnDemand with jira-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, authentication, oauth, rubygems, jira

has anyone here had any luck with jira-ruby gem to connect to JIRA onDemand ver 6.2?

I need to have a script in my local machine to connect to JIRA OnDemand to submit issues. I've read the API and had JIRA on my local machine to talk with my script fine. I also decided that OAuth is probably the way to go for the authentication to JIRA OnDemand.

I also have the admin account but i can't seem to get any URL that i type work..

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this

[Fixed Bug Report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5683)

and this

[Acces Jira from ruby Tutorial](https://blogs.reucon.com/srt/accessing-jira-from-ruby-8706/)

and this

[another Tutorial](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/02/jira-5-rubygem/)

next Time dont post the same question on different sites, and i may help you more....

Comment: Thanks and yes i posted the same question on different sites hoping that it would reach broader audience but if it's irritates you i apologize.

Comment: JIRA SOAP API is dead

Comment: @Tilo indeed indeed, REST is the future